# El uso de algunas etiquetas hacen que el título de la entrada se oculte

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Buenas Tardes:

Me está ocurriendo algo particular al utilizar algunas etiquetas y es que ocultan el título, me he dado cuenta probando, que al ocultarse el título el buscador del tema deja el espacio de la entrada, pero no la muestra. Alguien que me ayude por favor a descubrir qué tienen en particular esas entradas que hacen que el título de la entrada que lo usa lo oculta, las etiquetas son "españa" y "espantoso". Lo curioso es que sospeché que depronto el uso de caracteres especiales podía entorpecer el funcionamiento correcto de las etiquetas y me dí cuenta que esto no es cierto, porque creé entradas de prueba con etiquetas de prueba que contenían caracteres especiales y el título siempre se mostraba. Este es el código del archivo index.php del tema.Muchas gracias a todos.

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the home/index page.
 * This template will also be called in any case where the Wordpress engine 
 * doesn't know which template to use (e.g. 404 error)
 */

$layout = of_get_option('side_bar');
$layout = (empty($layout)) ? 'right_side' : $layout;
$ad_posts_mode = of_get_option('ad_posts_mode', 'none');
$ad_posts_frequency = of_get_option('ad_posts_frequency', 'none');
$ad_posts_box = of_get_option('ad_posts_box', true);

get_header(); ?>


<?php
    // Advert above content
    $ad_content_placement   = of_get_option('ad_content_placement', array('home' => true,'pages' => true,'posts' => true));
    $ad_content_mode        = of_get_option('ad_content_mode', 'none');
    $ad_content_box         = of_get_option('ad_content_box', true);
    $ad_content_padding         = of_get_option('ad_content_padding', true);

    if($ad_content_mode != 'none' and $ad_content_placement['home'] == true and is_home()){
        echo '<div class="above_content'.(($ad_content_box) ? ' box' : '').(($ad_content_padding) ? ' pad15' : '').'">';
            if($ad_content_mode == 'image'){
                echo '<a href="'.of_get_option('ad_content_image_link').'" target="_blank"><img src="'.of_get_option('ad_content_image').'"></a>';
            }elseif($ad_content_mode == 'html'){
                echo apply_filters('shortcode_filter',do_shortcode(of_get_option('ad_content_code')));
            }elseif($ad_content_mode == 'google_ads'){
                blu_get_google_ads(); 
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
    <div id="primary" class="row <?php echo $layout; ?>">

        <?php if($layout == 'both_side'){ ?>
        <aside id="side-bar" class="span3 widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_left' ); ?>
        </aside>
        <?php } ?>  

        <div id="content" class="<?php echo of_get_option('blog_layout'); ?> <?php echo ($layout == 'single') ? 'span10 offset1' : ($layout == 'both_side' ? 'span6' : 'span8'); ?>" role="main">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div id="above-blog" class="widget-area">
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'above_blog' ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="main_columns" class="columns">
                <?php 

                if( have_posts() ){ 
                    $x = 1;
                    while ( have_posts() ){
                        the_post(); 
                        get_template_part( 'inc/post-format/content', get_post_format() );
                        // advertising between posts
                        if($ad_posts_mode != 'none'){
                            // take into account ad frequency
                            if (($x % $ad_posts_frequency) == 0){

                                switch ($ad_posts_mode) {
                                    case 'image':
                                        echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts"><a target="_blank" href="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image_link').'"><img src="'.of_get_option('ad_posts_image').'"></a></div>';
                                    break;
                                    case 'html':
                                        echo '<div class="'.(($ad_posts_box) ? 'box' : '').' between_posts">'.apply_filters('shortcode_filter',do_shortcode(of_get_option('ad_posts_code'))).'</div>';
                                    break;
                                    case 'google_ads':
                                        blu_get_google_ads();
                                        echo '<br>'; 
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $x++;
                    }
                    wp_pagenavi();
                }else{ ?>
                <article class="type-page box">
                    <h1 class="title"><?php _e('Post not found', 'bluth'); ?></h1>
                    <div class="the-content">
                    <p class="lead"><?php _e('We could not find that post you were looking for.', 'bluth'); ?></p>
                    <br>
                    <h3><?php _e('Try searching', 'bluth') ?></h3>
                    <?php echo get_search_form(); ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'inc/recent-posts' ); ?>               
                    </div>
                </article>
                <?php } 

                // kriesi_pagination(); 

                ?> 
            </div><!-- .columns --><? kriesi_pagination(); ?>
        </div><!-- #content -->

        <?php if($layout == 'left_side'){ ?>
        <aside id="side-bar" class="span4 widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_left'); ?>
        </aside>
        <?php } ?>  
        <?php if($layout == 'right_side'){ ?>
        <aside id="side-bar" class="span4 widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_right' ); ?>
        </aside>
        <?php } ?>      
        <?php if($layout == 'both_side'){ ?>
        <aside id="side-bar" class="span3 widget-area">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_right' ); ?>
        </aside>
        <?php } ?>      
    </div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

En la url que es encuentra a continuación se evidencia el error: Se dejan espacios cada que una entrada no tiene título y no la muestra(la entrada).

Se puede probar en esta url; se filtró por la palabra "espa" y cuando se desplaza el scroll no muestra una de las entradas y esta por supuesto no tiene título, el uso de la etiqueta "espantoso" se lo oculta.

http://www.elcolombiano.com/blogs/elblogdericky/?s=espa

Comment: Hola, ¿Tendrás el código php, HTML y/o Javascript donde se pueda reproducir el problema que tienes para así poder ayudarte a resolver el problema? Porque así como está la pregunta no hay forma de llegar una respuesta en concreto. Por favor

Comment: Hola @Lixus, te agradezco que hayas respondido la pregunta. en cuanto al código fuente creó que será complicado hacerlo público, este código es de uso empresarial, pero digamos que si se necesita mirar cosas de configuración para empezar a descartar cosas, puedo ir tomando pantallazos, pero yo sinceramente no sé qué código especificamente agregar para ilustrar más el problema. Ya revisé y esas etiquetas tampoco están en el código. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Lixus o puedes decirme, agrega el código de tal archivo, algo así... pero yo no sabría qué código específicamente postear. Muchísimas gracias... Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Lixus , este es el index.php, hay un loop que recorre las entradas, en la línea 55.

Comment: Podría deberse a que las entradas con esas etiquetas en especial usen una plantilla diferente a las demás.  ¿Puedes verificar que una página que se ve normal y otra con problemas tienen **la misma plantilla**? Otro motivo puede ser que estés aplicando algún **estilo CSS** sólo a esas etiquetas y que te esté dando el problema. Claro, si se pudiera ver el código fuente sería mucho más fácil indicarte dónde podría estar el error. Ver la url de una de las páginas que te da problemas. Pues así, adivinando... difícil. Saludos.